# Jmeter Json POST Request Failing

Tags: json, jmeter, http-post

In Jmeter when submitting a POST request which includes Json string in the body the transaction is failing with below message and HTTP 500 error-

```
`{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}`
```

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong here?

Below is how the failing sample (REQ_2_1) request body looks like-

[Screenshot: Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z08Iu.jpg)

[Screenshot: Header for the POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHrhu.jpg)

[Json request Body - 1 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilrte.jpg)

[Json request Body - 2 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nccyL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You JSON body is wrong and break the JSON request:

[image]

It should probably be:

> "jsonString":"${MyJSONString}"

Comment: It is actually a very long json string. Please see the last screenshot I just uploaded in to the original thread